# How to align a network graph to an image?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing, image

An arbitrary example:

Create a random image

```
Image[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}], ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Define some points and a graph to align

```
c = PixelValuePositions[%, White, .1]
RandomGraph[Table[Length[c], 2]]
```

[image]

```
Out[1]: {{2, 9}, {1, 8}, {1, 7}, {2, 7}, {9, 6}, {2, 2}}
```

How can I align the nodes of a graph to coordinates on an image?

Ideally this would be a graph from a correlation matrix

```
RandomReal[{-1, 1}, Table[Length[c], 2]] // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
img = Image[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}], ImageSize -> Medium];
c = PixelValuePositions[img, White, .1];

rg = RandomGraph[Table[Length[c], 2], ImageSize -> Medium];

rg2 = SetProperty[rg, 
   {VertexCoordinates -> c - 1/2, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]}];

Row[{rg, Show[img, rg2]}]
```

[image]

Comment: How can I remove the self lines from a `WeightedAdjacencyGraph[]` of a correlation matrix? it seems the removal in the help is done by setting to infinite but this seems there may be a setting I can not see

Comment: @Teabelly, replacing 0's with `Infinity`s is the only way I know.